# I'm trying to create a web page that contains 3 JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
// Create an object:
var person1 = {Title: "Title: A Song of Ice and Fire", Author: "Author: George RR Martin", Type:"Type: Paperback", Price:19.99};
var person2 = {Title:"Title: The Woman in the Window", Author:"Author: A.J. Finn", Type:"Type: Paperback", Price:6.29};
var person3 = {Title:"Title: The Silkworm", Author:"Author: Robert Galbraith", Type:"Type: Hardback", Price:14.99};

// Display some data from the object:
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = person1.Title;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = person1.Author;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = person1.Type;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = person1.Price;

document.getElementById("code1").innerHTML = person2.Title;
document.getElementById("code2").innerHTML = person2.Author;
document.getElementById("code3").innerHTML = person2.Type;
document.getElementById("code4").innerHTML = person2.Price;

document.getElementById("job1").innerHTML = person3.Title;
document.getElementById("job2").innerHTML = person3.Author;
document.getElementById("job3").innerHTML = person3.Type;
document.getElementById("job4").innerHTML = person3.Price;
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>

<button onclick="show(0)">Book 1</button>
<button onclick="show(1)">Book 2</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">Book 3</button>

<h3>Book 1</h3>
<p id="demo1"></p>         
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>

<h3>Book 2</h3>
<p id="code1"></p>
<p id="code2"></p>
<p id="code3"></p>
<p id="code4"></p>

<h3>Book 3</h3>
<p id="job1"></p>
<p id="job2"></p>
<p id="job3"></p>
<p id="job4"></p>

</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is that when I click on the buttons for book 1, book 2 or book 3 that the object will be displayed for example if I click on the button Book 1 the book title, Author, Type, Price and image will be displayed Im stuck om how im supposed to do this and would be grateful for help on this.

Comment: Hi Akeem, what is your effort so far for creating this page and displaying the books?

Comment: Hi Akeem, what have you tried so far? Are you trying to do this in *just* JavaScript? or do you have any additional libraries?

Comment: Consider using [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. 
To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide 
some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what 
you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, 
please take some time to read [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
 and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh so ive been trying to get my book objects to be printed out but ive been unsuccessful so far im just using javascript

Comment: The problem im having is when I click on the book 1 button the objects aren't displayed like a list thats my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let book1 = { title: "A Song of Ice and Fire", author: "George RR Martin", type: "Paperback", price: 19.99, image: "songoficeandfire.jpg" }
let book2 = { title: "The Woman in the Window", author: "A.J. Finn", type: "Paperback", price: 6.29, image: "womaninwindow.jpg"}
let book3 = { title: "The Silkworm", author: "Robert Galbraith", type: "Hardback", price: 14.99, image: "silkworm.jpg" }

let books = [book1, book2, book3];

function show(index) {
  msg.innerText = JSON.stringify(books[index], null, 4);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show(0)">Show book1</button>
<button onclick="show(1)">Show book2</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">Show book3</button>

<pre id="msg"></pre>
```